# Databinding не работает на мейн треде

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Есть `ObservableBool`, от которого что-то в `layout` зависит, что-то меняется.

Если в этот `ObservableBool` я что-то запишу без `RxJava`

```
houseField.oEnabled.set(true)
```

то, в `layout` что-то поменяется, как и нужно
а если я выполню этот код в

```
Handler().postDelayed({
      houseField.oEnabled.set(true)
      Utils.toast("Jg2")
    }, 3000)
```

или в

```
Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe({
        houseField.oEnabled.set(true)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        Utils.toast("Jg")
      }, Timber::e)
```

ТО в лэйоуте ничего не поменяется. `executePendingBindings()` не помогает, `Handler` и `Observable.timer` вызываются в `onViewCreated` фрагмента

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?